# How to fix iOS crash "EXC_BREAKPOINT UNKNOWN"?

Tags: xcode, swift, crash

I have in my app this type of crash:

[image]

Line 144 is this:

```
if singleProfile == true
```

And variable declaration is this:

```
var singleProfile: Bool = false
```

I really don't understand why it crashes :(

Comment: Where is `singleProfile` declared? Is it a property of a class? Where is it being called? Is the `if singleProfile == true` line inside a function, or somewhere else? A little more context may help answer your question. (As a side note, you don't need to write `if singleProfile == true` - you can just write `if singleProfile`. You shouldn't need to compare it to `true`. But that shouldn't be causing your crash...)

Comment: I have the same situation.
I think "if singleProfile == true" or "if singleProfile" is the same meaning.
so it can run whether "if singleProfile == true" or "if singleProfile"
so I think this problem has other causes.

any solution?

Comment: I resolved.it is not relation with "if singleProfile == true" or "if singleProfile".

Comment: i would like to see your program around error position.

Comment: @shunsuke_stackoverflow I'm having this same crash, and for me it's on an `if something == true` line too. How did you fix it?

Comment: Hi @shunsuke_stackoverflow, mind sharing what you did to resolve this issue?

Comment: I am also having similar problem, @shunsuke_stackoverflow would you share your fix please to get some insights? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I have seen EXC_BREAKPOINT UNKNOWN happens when you are unwrapping an optional but the value inside is nil. Please check unwrapping optionals code.